# Process automatically starting on a port in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: process, kill, lsof, port

I have encountered a very weird situation. I am using below command to list all processes running on a particular port 3001:

```
sudo lsof -n -i :3001
```

Only one process is printed each time and I kill that process using `sudo kill -9 pid`. But as I run the lsof command again, i again notice that there is one more process with some random Pid. I delete it as well and the process goes on. It means my port is never free. How do I kill all process on this port?

Thank You!

Comment: `process` is not very descriptive. *Which* process exactly? It might be a daemon that keeps getting restarted - in that case, `kill` is not the right approach.

Comment: Actually I was trying to start npm module ``json-server`` but it couldn't start. I tried 5-6 times. No as I run ``ps -ef``, I see the json-server running process( actually it is not running) with a pid. Then I kill it using that pid. But as I run ``ps -ef`` again, it again appears with a different pid. I kill it again. This process is never ending.

Comment: What I basically want to do is to free my port 3001. I process of freeing it, found the above stated problem. Now you please tell me how to free my port 3001.

Comment: Stop the daemon (service) which keeps restarting `json-server`. I don't know your system or what daemons you are running.

Comment: I didn't start any daemon on my own. So I don't know how to stop it.

Comment: facing same situation and no command works, tried everything available in the internet

Answer (score 0):

Run :
`systemctl status`
Will give you all services that starts on system start and these are daemon services. Figure out which service could be using that port(3001) and stop it using `sudo serivce 'servicename' stop`.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank your for your contribution. Please note however that this only works if the process is actually started using `systemd`, and not some other auto-start mechanism (or a manually started program that re-spawns child processes listening on that port if previous ones are killed).